# Dynamic Use Of MapHttpRoute

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm looking for a dynamic way of using MapHttpRoute.
My route is:

```
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "RouteReports",
            routeTemplate: "r2/{controller}/{clientId}/{action}",
            defaults: new { action = "adherence", controller = "reports" }
            );
```

**Currently I have 2 methods:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("adherence")]
    public AdherenceReport GetAdherenceReport(string clientId)  {  } 

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("adherence")]
    public AdherenceReport GetAdherenceReport(string clientId, int year, int month) {  }
```

Currently, both methods work nicely. I prefer using only **one method**.
I want to be able to support different kinds of requests:

```
r2/reports/client1/adherence
r2/reports/client1/adherence?year=2015&month=8
r2/reports/client1/adherence?month=8
r2/reports/client1/adherence?year=2015
```

**EDIT:** Right now, only the first and second requests work. The third and fourth returns an error.

Is it possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make your `year` and `month` parameters optional (and maybe even `nullable`) it will work:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("adherence")]
public AdherenceReport GetAdherenceReport(string clientId)  {  } 

[HttpGet]
[ActionName("adherence")]
public AdherenceReport GetAdherenceReport(string clientId, int year = 0, int month = 0) {  }
```

Inside the method, you simply check for those values and act accordingly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunatley, Neither of them (init and nullable) worked.

Comment: What doesn't work?  Do you get an exception or is the method not called?

Comment: Sorry, my bad - forgot to uncomment something. Works Perfect, Thanks man.

Comment: Awesome!  Glad I could help.